# 'value' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, alamofire

Setting up API for openweathermap. However, when it comes to setting up this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location  = locations[0]
        lat = location.coordinate.latitude
        lon = location.coordinate.longitude
        AF.request("http://api.openweathermaps.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&appid=\(apiKey)&units=metric").responseJSON {
            response in
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            if let responseStr = response.result.value {
                let jsonResponse = JSON(responseStr)
                let jsonWeather  = jsonResponse["weather"].array![0]
                let jsonTemp = jsonResponse["main"]
                let iconName =  jsonWeather["icon"].stringValue
            }
        }

    }
```

I get the error:

> 'value' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Comment: I have run into this issue before, have you tried making that func public?

Comment: how do you go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for trying Alamofire 5! This error is a bit misleading, as the Swift compiler is trying to be helpful and letting you know there's an `internal` property `value` on `response.result` that you can't access. However, this is an internal Alamofire extension, as we moved to the [`Result` type provided by the Swift standard library](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0235-add-result.md) in Alamofire 5 beta 4. The system `Result` does not offer the the `value` and `error` properties that Alamofire's previously provided `Result` type did. So while we have extensions internally to provide functionality to us, they do not exist publicly for use by your app.

The ultimate solution here is up to you. You can extend `Result` yourself to offer the properties (feel free to use the Alamofire implementation) or you can do without the properties and `switch` over the `response.result` value to extract the response value. I would suggest using `switch` for now, as it forces you to consider the `.failure` case.

Comment: This has been changed in Alamofire 5 beta 7: our internal extensions no longer use the `value` / `error` properties, so this error should no longer occur. Instead you should see a normal "no such property" error.

Answer (score 3):

```
switch response.result {
        
        case .success(let value):
            print("Alamo value: \(value)")
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Alamo error: \(error)")
            break
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest `beta 4` version Alamofire switched to using the new standard Result type, so the convenience properties we used to have have been made internal. Now you can switch over the result like this:

```
switch response.result {
    case let .success(value): ...
    case let .failure(error): ...
}
```

Or you can make similar extensions in your own project. They won't be offering the extensions publicly anymore.