# "'isSuccess' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level", AlamoFire not working like before

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Im using alamoFire on swift but i came across this problem: "isSuccess' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level".
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484714/value-is-inaccessible-due-to-internal-protection-level) and i have also tried [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2790),
here is my code:

```
AF.request(jsonURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
       if response.result.isSuccess { //problem is here
            print("Got the info")
            print(response)
            
            let flowerJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            let list = flowerJSON["..."]["..."]["..."].stringValue
            
           print(list)
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`result` is now of the built-in [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) enum type, which means you can do pattern matching on it. Your code can be rewritten as:

```
AF.request("", method: .get, parameters: [:]).responseJSON { (response) in
    if case .success(let value) = response.result {
        print("Got the info")
        print(response)
        
        let flowerJSON : JSON = JSON(value)
        ...
    }
}
```

Use a switch statement if you want the error case as well:

```
switch response.result {
case .success(let value):
    // ...
case .failure(let error):
    // ...
}
```